# Clarification of expect script regex evaluation

Tags: regex, syntax, match, expect

I have been teaching myself expect scripting and I have a few clarification questions regarding expect script regex expressions. I have created a code that spawns a Sun iLOM ssh session and then enables the SNMP agent. As it turns out iLOM2 and iLOM3 handle this process differently, so I create this script to solve that issue. While trying to figure out how to make a regex match properly I encountered many conflicting solutions online and I am now rather confused. The best help I found was the [expect manpage](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html). I managed to get something to work, but I fear my solution is dirty and it doesn't match any of the example I have found. So my actual question: How is my code working? Is there a better way?

I hope to learn more about Expect scripting as opposed to just blindly meshing custom solutions together.

**NOTE:** Again, this code works. I would like to learn how it evaluates.

Output to capture:

```
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@<host>
Password: 

Sun(TM) Integrated Lights Out Manager

Version 2.0.2.6

Copyright 2008 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.
Use is subject to license terms.

->
```

The idea is to capture "Version 2." and then extract the number 2 from there.

Expect script snippet:

```
set prompt "\\\->"
send "$pwd\r"
    expect {
            timeout { ...timeout action... }
            $prompt { ...regex didn't match action... }
            -indices -re {(Version (\d+).)} {
            #Regex to find ILOM Version.
                    if {[info exists expect_out(2,string)]} {
                            set ilom_version $expect_out(2,string)
                    } else { ...regex didn't match properly action...  }
                    expect $prompt
            }
    }
```

The exact regex there is *-indices -re {(Version (\d+).)}*. It took me a long time to eventually figure out a syntax that works because the expect manpage I linked above has examples that are entirely different. ie: *-re "failed|invalid password"* Whenever I adopted that syntax everything falls apart. *"Version", Version, {Version}, (Version)* ALL fail.

So I guess I am just confused on how my code IS working and why it's so different than all the examples I found. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is that which is enclosed with `{}`.

```
(Version (\d+).)
```

It will match a string containing `Version` followed by a space then one or more digits followed by one of any character. The dot is the wildcard character that matches any character; if you want to match a literal `.` use `\.`.

You have enclosed the pattern in `()` so the whole match will be captured and saved in `expect_out(1,string)`. But as *a)* you are not using the whole match, and *b)* the whole match is automatically saved in `expect_out(0,string)` anyway, the outer brackets are unnecessary.

You have also enclosed the `\d+` in brackets so the leading digits of the version number will be captured and saved in `expect_out(2,string)`, but if you remove the outer brackets as suggested above, it will be saved in `expect_out(1,string)`.

The `.` or a `\.` following the digits does not really serve any purpose, beyond preventing a match if that character is not there.

The `-indices` flag is unnecessary as you're not seeking the index of the matches.

Otherwise, your method for extracting the version number looks fine - although, I know next to nothing about Expect :)

Comment: Thank you MikeM. So I just tested `-r {Version (\d+)}` with `$expect_out(1,string)` and it works!
I guess when I tried that approach before it must have been failing because I didn't adjust the $expect_out variable to find the new match index. Also, I was using the trailing period to defend against a greedy addition operator; however, it looks like it isn't necessary.

Cool! I feel better about this. Thank you.
Alas, I have less than 15 rep so I cannot +1 you. Would if I could though.